# How to get Redis PID in redis-cli interface?

Tags: redis

How to get Redis PID in redis-cli interface?

```
[illidan@CentOS7 ~]$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> help
```

I hope i can get the redis pid without back to OS interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `INFO` command can print the `process_id` info in the `[Server]` section.

Comment: So, being a little more explicit you can type `INFO server` at the CLI and look for the field called `process_id`.